# Postgres Overlap in System and Local DB Table Name

Tags: sql, postgresql, postico

I ran into a strange issue where I have a `user` table in my local DB, which appears to overlap with the postgres system table `user` when I try to run SQL queries using Postico. While I am running queries against my db, I am returned a `current_user` column that maps to the username accessing the db. What should I change to my SQL to point to the local DB user table?

SQL commands I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
;
```

**Returned `current_user: johndoe`**

```
UPDATE user
SET user.password = 'cryptopw', user.authentication_token = NULL
WHERE user.user_id = 210;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USER` is one of the **reserved** [key words for PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). It is also reserved for SQL 2011, 2008 and 92.

From the documentation:

> SQL distinguishes between **reserved** and non-reserved key words. According to the standard, **reserved key words are the only real key words; they are never allowed as identifiers.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

That is, if you want to avoid trouble, don't use `user` as an identifier (that is: it shouldn't be the name of a table, or a column, or an index, or a constraint, or a function, ...).

If you still want to try:

> As a general rule, if you get spurious parser errors for commands that contain any of the listed key words as an identifier you should try to **quote the identifier** to see if the problem goes away.

That is, try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "user" ;
```

and

```
UPDATE 
    "user"
SET 
    password = 'cryptopw',        -- not "user".password
    authentication_token = NULL   -- not "user". authentication_token
WHERE 
    "user".user_id = 210;         -- you can, but don't need "user"
```

I would actually rename the table, call it `my_user` (or `application_user` or something else), follow the SQL standard, and forget about having to quote identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This have been extremely helpful and I agree, I should choose a new name for my table.